# Not able to fetch pool in whirlpool SDK

Tags: solana-program

```
let url="https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(url); // Connect to devnet
const ctx = WhirlpoolContext.withProvider(connection, "whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc");
let poolAddress= new PublicKey("Czfq3xZZDmsdGdUyrNLtRhGc47cXcZtLG4crryfu44zE");
```

let poolDetails= await ctx.fetcher.getPool(poolAddress);
console.log(poolDetails);

Comment: What error are you getting?